# Access documents of linked collections MongoDB Nodejs Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express-handlebars

I am an amateur web developer and I am trying a project where I create a bug-tracking platform. Below is a screenshot of my dashboard. The column titled "Reported by" shows the user ID of the user that reported the bug. My aim is to not show the user ID but the name of the user instead.
[image]

I have tried several attempts but keep hitting a brick wall. The relevant technologies I am using are Nodejs, Express, Handlebars, and MongoDB

I have two collections; User and Ticket. I have linked the User collection in the Ticket collection.

**User Collection**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    userType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'Tester',
        enum: ['Tester', 'Admin']
    }
}, {timestamps: true})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**Ticket Collection**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const TicketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }, 
    tType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Development', 'Testing', 'Production']
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Open',
        enum: ['Open', 'Resolved', 'Closed']
    },
    priority: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']
    },
    assignedTo: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Julian', 'Jeremiah', 'Madani', 'Yassine', 'Nate']
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
}, {timestamps: true})

const Ticket = mongoose.model('Ticket', TicketSchema);
module.exports = Ticket;
```

**My index page**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuth, ensureGuest } = require('../config/auth');
const Ticket = require('../models/Ticket');
const User = require('../models/User');

// Dashboard page
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const tickets = await Ticket.find({ user: req.user.id }).lean()
        const userName = await User.find({}, {_id: 1, name: 1}).lean() // Me trying to access the User collection
        if(tickets.user == userName._id) {
            res.render('dashboard.hbs', {
                name: req.user.name,
                userType: req.user.userType,
                tickets,
                userName
            })
        }
        
        console.log(userName)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.render('error/500.hbs')
    }

})

module.exports = router;
```

**And finally, my handlebars template**

```
{{#if tickets}}
    {{!-- {{#ifEquals tickets.user userName._id}} --}}
    {{#ifEquals userType "Admin"}}
        <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-active">
            <th scope="col">Ticket Number/ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Ticket Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Priority</th>
            <th scope="col">Reported by</th>
            <th scope="col">Assigned</th>
            <th scope="col">When</th>
            {{!-- <th scope="col"></th>

            <th scope="col"></th> --}}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each tickets}}
                <tr class="taable-default">
                <th scope="row"><a href="/tickets/{{_id}}">{{_id}}</a></th>
                <td>{{title}}</td>
                <td><span class="dash-status">{{status}}</span></td>
                <td>{{priority}}</td>
                <td>{{user}}</td>
                <td>{{assignedTo}}</td>
                <td>{{formatDate createdAt 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}</td>
                {{!-- <td></td>
                <td></td> --}}
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
        </table>
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of I used the mongoose method **[`findById()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)** to search for a mongodb document using it's Objectid. After that, I added the `user` variable to render it with `dashboard.hbs`

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuth, ensureGuest } = require('../config/auth');
const Ticket = require('../models/Ticket');
const User = require('../models/User');

// Dashboard page
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const tickets = await Ticket.find({ user: req.user.id }).lean()
        const user = await User.findById(tickets.user).lean() // Me trying to access the User collection
        if(tickets.user == user._id) {
            return res.render('dashboard.hbs', { // I would return here
                name: req.user.name,
                userType: req.user.userType,
                tickets,
                user
            })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.render('error/500.hbs') // I would return here
    }

})

module.exports = router;
```

What you need to change in your handlebars file is to simply request `user.name`, which we determined earlier to render the `dashboard.hbs` template:

```
{{#if tickets}}
    {{!-- {{#ifEquals tickets.user user._id}} --}}
    {{#ifEquals userType "Admin"}}
        <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-active">
            <th scope="col">Ticket Number/ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Ticket Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Priority</th>
            <th scope="col">Reported by</th>
            <th scope="col">Assigned</th>
            <th scope="col">When</th>
            {{!-- <th scope="col"></th>

            <th scope="col"></th> --}}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each tickets}}
                <tr class="taable-default">
                <th scope="row"><a href="/tickets/{{_id}}">{{_id}}</a></th>
                <td>{{title}}</td>
                <td><span class="dash-status">{{status}}</span></td>
                <td>{{priority}}</td>
                <td>{{../user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{assignedTo}}</td>
                <td>{{formatDate createdAt 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}</td>
                {{!-- <td></td>
                <td></td> --}}
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
        </table>
...
...
```